# Sum a list without recursion/looping in Scheme/Racket

Tags: scheme

I'm working on an assignment involving Racket and I was hoping somebody could lead me into the right direction.

I must calculate the norm of a list without recursion or using a loop and without defining any helper functions.

Is this possible? The only thing that comes to mind is to somehow use the built-in map functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (norm lst)
  (apply + (map square lst)))
```